# Deleting an image once the lookup cell is blank

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new Macros and from tutorials on youtube I have managed to create a running document, where when I type a saved image name into a cell the image is returned. 
However the issue I am having is when I delete the image name from the cell, the image remains in the spreadsheet.
Also if I overtype the existing image name with another, the new picture just overlays the old without deleting.

Please is anyone able to help me solve this problem, my current code is as below:

```
Sub InsertPictures(oRange As Range)
   Dim oCell As Range

   For Each oCell In oRange.Cells
      If oCell.Value <> "" Then
         ' See if this contains a picture
         InsertPicture oCell
    End If
   Next
End Sub

Sub InsertPicture(oCell As Range)
   Dim sPicName As String
   Dim oFSO As Object
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim p As Object


sPicName = oCell.Value
   If sPicName = "" Then Exit Sub
   Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If Not oFSO.FileExists("Libraries\Pictures\” & sPicName & ".jpg") Then 
Exit Sub ' Pic not found

   ' Insert picture
   Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("Libraries\Pictures\” & sPicName & ".jpg")

   ' Ensure placed in correct location
   With p
   .Top = oCell.Top
   .Left = oCell.Left
   .Height = 275
   .Width = 275
   End With
 End Sub

Sub test()
   Dim oEndCell As Range

   Set oEndCell = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
   InsertPictures ActiveSheet.Range("A1", oEndCell)
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like 2 issues to me - **1 - delete picture, if the name is deleted** and **2 - make sure that the pictures do not overlap**. Is it so?

Comment: Yes that it right. But to clarify images only overlap because the original does not delete when the name is deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure will remove a picture by passing the range to check:

```
Sub removePicture(picRange As Range)

    Dim shapeObj As Shape

    For Each shapeObj In picRange.Parent.Shapes

        If shapeObj.TopLeftCell = picRange Then
            shapeObj.Delete
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

You can incorporate it into your code by calling it when you either delete or change the image name in the cell (I assume this is based on a Worksheet_Change event).

Comment: Hi, I added what you suggested into my code, but my images remain in the spreadsheet even  once their image name have been deleted. Apologies I am not sure what you mean by Worksheet_Change event (am a very basic level at the moment!), is that where the macro auto runs based on a change in the information? At the moment I am manually asking the macro to run (Alt+F8)

Comment: @M.Excel - Yes, that is how `Worksheet_Change` event works. If you are running it manually, make sure you run the `removePicture` procedure **before** inserting the new picture. And make sure you pass the correct range.

Comment: so I have incorporated your `removePicture` code at the beginning of my above code so that I am asking the sheet to remove any existing images before inserting, but nothing happens. The sheet with your code included will now not even add images to new cells with the image name. What does pass the correct range mean?

Comment: I have worked it out, thank you for your help. I set `removePicture` up as a separate module and inserted x2 command buttons (one for inserting and one for deleting) and my sheet works.